# Changing variable names within a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What am I doing wrong here (MATLAB)?

I want to obtain some lines like the ones below:

```
syms B D M L
expr11 = -M-B*L*(B-M-D);
JQDFE11 = simplify(expr11);
```

with the following loop:

```
for k=1:8
LHS=['JQDFE1',num2str(k)];
RHS=['expr1',num2str(k)];
eval('LHS = simplify(RHS)');
end
```

but I am getting the error:

```
Error using eval: Undefined function 'simplify' for input arguments of type 'char'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get this working. Both `LHS` and `RHS` are **strings** whereas in your code, they are interpreted as variables.  You want:

```
eval([LHS ' = simplify(' RHS ')']);
```

`LHS` and `RHS` are actually names to variables but are stored as strings, and so you want to use the actual strings when building up your string to `eval`.  BTW, I don't know why you are doing what you're doing, but consider **not** using `eval`.  It's bad practice.  See this post by Loren Shure from MathWorks on why you shouldn't use it: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/

Comment: And [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) some alternatives for `eval` can be found.

Comment: @Matt - Very nice.  Didn't realize this was finally placed in the documentation.  I've always referred people to Loren Shure's post as it's the most canonical. Thanks!